# Moving a file with Administrator Permissions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server running 2012.

I have a file in a directory, and I wish to move it to a sub directory, which I do by dragging and dropping.

I get an error telling me I require admin priveleges to do this.

I search for file explorer in the TRULY AWFUL 2012 startmenu and find it but it won't allow me to run as administrator.

How can I drag and drop this file?

Comment: Instead of drag-and-dropping, could you `robocopy` via administrative command prompt instead?

Comment: Maybe but that's not the point, I want to know how to drag & drop

Comment: I did wonder, thinking the Q had a "how do I hit a nail in with this screwdriver" vibe; but figured the comment would be useful for those who don't know about `robocopy`. In that case, start your administrative command prompt, and run `explorer`, which should get you an administrative-privileged version of that :)

Comment: (posted as an answer)

Answer (score 2):

### How can I click-drag to move a folder that needs admin permissions in explorer?

1. <kbd>Win+X</kbd> --> `Command prompt (admin)` (alternatively right click the `Start` tile in `Desktop` mode)
2. `explorer` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Using the new administrative `explorer` window, click and drag to move the folder

Answer (score 1):

In order to move something that requires admin privileges, you will have to go through the UAC process in order to move it. Launching Windows Explorer as an administrator will enable you to drag and drop. This can be done with the right click context menu, or launch command prompt with administrator privileges and type 'explorer.exe' then hit enter